# Angular2: changing value of input

Tags: angular

In my input I enter `123`. On submit I want to have `456`.

How to change an input value?

My HTML (Ionic2)

```
<ion-textarea [ngFormControl]="message"></ion-textarea>
```

JavaScript

```
this.message.value = '456';
console.log('>>>', this.message.value); // output is '123'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use 2 way binding 
Something like:

```
<ion-textarea [(ngFormControl)]="message"></ion-textarea>
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not working. Is the issue deeper?